# Problema con CSS al vincularla con HTML

Tags: html, css

Holaa!!
De nuevo yo con una mega duda (problema)

quiero vincular mi hoja de estilo (css) a mi  html, quizás no tengan el permiso  adecuado para ser vinculadas.
pero son diferentes carpetas. Una está dentro de la carpeta public_html
y la otra está fuera de ésta pero está dentro de la carpeta Estilo, como pueden ver en la siguiente imagen.

[image: Mi ubicación actual de ambas carpetas y el link]
Y aquí pongo el error de consola:

[image: Error de consola]

Comment: Entiendo que el problema es que no detecta los estilos no? Has probado a poner la ruta como si ya estuvieses en el root del proyecto? (quiero decir './Estilos/Styles.css'). Para comprobarlo te sugiero que desde el navegador (por ejemplo Chrome) abras la consola, vayas al apartado del "Source" y compruebes que el fichero se está cargando.

Comment: Justamente lo  acabo  de hacer y  me aparece error justo en eso.
Quisiera poder mostrartelo aqui mismo pero lo tendré que poner en la publicación XD

Comment: Estas seguro de que esa carpeta es accesible desde el lado del cliente? A través de la URL intenta acceder al fichero .css para ver si desde el navegador puedes acceder a el. Si no es así intenta mover la carpeta de estilos desntro de la carpeta public_html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cuando pones / al inicio te vas a la raiz del proyecto y si antes pones los dos punto .. estas saliendo del proyecto. Prueba con una de las siguientes

```
<link href="/Estilo/Style.css" .....>
```

o

```
<link href="..Estilo/Style.css" .....>
```

Además, todos los archivos de la pagina (js , css, html, php, etc) los tienes que meter dentro de la carpeta public_html , si quieres dentro puedes crear carpetas pero siempre dentro de public_html, por que es esta carpeta la que tiene los permisos necesarios para que cargue la página

Comment: Nop,  eso no me lo resuelve 7u7

Comment: ahh jolin, me acabo de dar cuenta, te edito mi respuesta

Comment: LoL okey muuchas gracias :3

Comment: genial, me alegro de ayudar, no olvides marcar la pregunta como resuelta. Saludos

Comment: Realmente aún no está resulta. Me sigue soltando el mismo  error... :/*
E ibas a editar tu  respuesta...no?

Comment: :p ya edite , pensé que te habia funcionado y por eso dabas las gracias,  revisa mi respuesta en la parte de abajo he añadido.

Comment: LOOOL No me había dado cuenta XDD
Ahora si muuchas gracias :3
Me podrías recomendar algún software bueno para html o con NB*
me quedo, por favor
*NetBeans

Comment: si para empezar esta bien NetBeans , por que te crea un servidor local y tiene muchas ayudas para autocompletado de codigo y además te marca muy bien los errores